# How do I use protractor with firefox and local self-signed https?

Tags: firefox, https, protractor

I'm using protractor to test an application and webdriver-manager doesn't seem to want to install an appropriate Chrome driver, so I'm trying Firefox instead. However, the test gets stuck at the security warning page of my self-signed `https://` test server. How do I configure protractor / selenium webdriver to skip the warning page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this block in your `protractor.conf.js` to load Firefox, and ignore the certificate error presented by the test server's self-signed certificate. Note that if you're editing a Chrome config it's not enough  to change `browserName`, you must remove any `chromeOptions: {`  to avoid confusing the test runner.

```
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        // command line options could go here
    },
    'acceptInsecureCerts': true
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

> In order to run protractor tests on multiple browsers, Protractor
>   offers a multiCapabilities configuration option. These options should
>   be defined as an array of objects.

**1. Capabilities to be passed to the web driver instance.**

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'firefox',
},
```

**2. How to execute protractor tests on multiple browsers in parallel using multiCapabilities.**

```
 multiCapabilities: [
    {'browserName': 'chrome'},
    {'browserName': 'firefox'},
  ],
```

**3. How we can do it using multiCapabilities.**

```
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['disable-infobars']
            }
        },
        {
            'browserName': 'firefox',
            'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            'args': ['--safe-mode']
            }
        }
   ],
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I had to add the 'acceptInsecureCerts': true option in order to use the local self-signed https://